# How to specify a timer's name depending on the chip it will be compiled to?

Tags: arduino-nano, interrupt, timers, attiny, pointer

I need to enable a timer interrupt for a chip, and in the mean time, I am testing the code on Arduino Nano rather than `(feed the chip, test the chip)++`.

So as part of the code I have to `TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);` which works great on the Arduino Nano, but has to be changed to `TIMSK` (without the 0) for the ATtiny45.

I was planning to go for something along the line of

```
#define NANO//Put // in front for the AtTiny45
#ifdef NANO
  const char in  = A0;
  const char out = 3;
  const char pwr = 10;
  char *timer = &TIMSK0;
#else
  const char in  = 3;
  const char out = 0;
  const char pwr = 1;
  char *timer = &TIMSK;
#endif
//...
*timer  |= (1 << OCIE0A);
```

So here are my three questions:

- Do #these commands take space on a chip?
- Is a pointer the way to go for this kind of things?
- Am, am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a complement to Delta_G's answer:

2. The names `TIMSK0`, `OCIE0A`, etc. are already preprocessor macros
   so, for consistency, it makes sense to define your own preprocessor
   macros for them. I tend to be lazy and use one of the already defined
   names, like

   ```cpp
   #ifdef TIMSK0  // support both ATtiny{25,45,85} and ATmega328P
   # define TIMSK TIMSK0
   #endif
   ```

   A `const` pointer for `&TIMSK0` is fine though.
3. The macros identifying the MCU are defined to the value 1. Thus you
   have the choice between these three idioms:

   ```cpp
   #ifdef __AVR_ATtiny45__
   ...
   #endif

   #if defined(__AVR_ATtiny45__)
   ...
   #endif

   #if __AVR_ATtiny45__
   ...
   #endif
   ```

   The third one is convenient when you want to address several MCU
   models with the same code:

   ```cpp
   #if __AVR_ATtiny25__ || __AVR_ATtiny45__ || __AVR_ATtiny85__
   ...
   #endif
   ```